# How to hide one2many's field column in tree view based on parent field value in odoo9

Tags: treeview, odoo-9

I have created a new field in sale order line named as "**Price1**" and "**Price_chk**" boolean field in Sale order. The field "**Price1**" should be invisible in tree view when the field "**Price_chk**" is False and it should be visible when the field "**Price_chk**" is True.

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide field conditionally in tree/list view, you can invisible but that should be fixed for all data not conditionally.

You can only set readonly and required (if treeview is editable).

**Solution:**

You can use two different treeview, for that you need to create two menus and two separate actions, in that action you need to specify view and domain.